# Name Tagger in Stanford NLP

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

Is there any good library in stanfordNLP which is meant for name parsing? Basically i want to separate first name, last name, nickname, surname, givenname from the full name. Something similar to HumanName and parserator.tag, parserator.parse? Lets say i have a name `Mr George "Gob" Bluth II` and if i use parserator.parse, it gives me below output. Is there something like this in stanford NLP?

```
>>> probablepeople.parse('Mr George "Gob" Bluth II')  
[('Mr', 'PrefixMarital'), ('George', 'GivenName'), ('"Gob"', 'Nickname'), ('Bluth', 'Surname'), ('II', 'SuffixGenerational')]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Name parsing does not appear to built-in to [Stanford CoreNLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/).
.

One option is writing a series of Regular Expression using [Stanford TokensRegex](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokensregex.html) to parse and label name tokens.

Another option is using a third party package, such as [nameparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nameparser) in Python.